# SSIS 2012 - Package deployment: CreateDeploymentUtility property not visible in project properties

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS 2012 project with many packages to deploy to a server.
As written [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137952.aspx) I have to create a Deployment Utility but in my project properties there is no Deployment Utility submenu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to deploy to SSMS. To deploy the SSIS project right click your project in the 'solutions explorer' and click deploy. Follow the steps and it will be available in SSMS under 'Integration Services Catalogs'.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'd like to deploy to the IS server, not to the SQL Server. I've already deployed my project to Integration Services Catalog but it's not what I want. The problem is that BIDS doesn't let me see the IS server's folders so I can't deploy to that destination...

Comment: Maybe this link might set you on the right course: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231102.aspx